# Creating a class attribute dependent on another attribute without overwriting

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have the class `Vehicle` that has two attributes: `pRange` and `pBattery`

There is an equal chance that the vehicle has a `pRange` of 220, 310, 400, or 505. I want the `pBattery` attribute to have a value that is dependent on the `pRange` value.

Here is my code:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, pRange, pBattery):
        self.pRange = np.random.choice(list(pRange), p = list(pRange.values()))
        self.pBattery = pBattery
    

pRange = { 220 : 0.25, 310 : 0.25, 400 : 0.25, 505 : 0.25 } 

b = Vehicle(pRange, pBattery)

if b.pRange == 220:
    b.pBattery == 36
elif b.pRange == 310:
    b.pBattery == 47.5
elif b.pRange == 400:
    b.pBattery = 64
elif b.pRange == 505:
    b.pBattery = 95

print(b.pRange)
print(b.pBattery)
```

which actually gives the correct result but I'm sure that there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: Use a dict. ....

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that's not very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, pRange):
        self.pBattteryDict = {220:36, 310:47.5, 400:64, 505:95}
        self.pRange = np.random.choice(list(pRange), p = list(pRange.values()))
        self.pBattery = self.pBattteryDict[self.pRange] 

pRange = { 220 : 0.25, 310 : 0.25, 400 : 0.25, 505 : 0.25 } 
b = Vehicle(pRange)

print(b.pRange)
print(b.pBattery)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks man :) I had tried something similar but it didn't work. Cheers